# Getting data from a database in angular

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb

I'm new to fullstack apps, and I just managed to implement facebook authentication with passport.  Right now I have my schema/models set up properly, and passport is saving facebook profile in mongodb the way I want.

Now I want entries in mongodb to talk to my Angular code.  Right now I did a hack in my passport routes, where if there is a req.user (which has a facebook object per mongoose schema), I set that user to rootScope.user in Angular with the usage of cookies as below (see the res.send of the cookie in passport code all the way at the bottom).

```
var user = $cookies.user;
$rootScope.currentUser = user;
```

this is obviously not a good idea for scalability. How do I grab the facebook data stored in mongo (thanks to passport), and get Angular to talk with it? I imagine some kind of $http request to a route.  Would I make that request to, say '/profile' as below in my passport code? I'm pretty confused and I know that this is a core concept that I need to understand.

```
// if no error, this gets hit:
app.get('/auth/facebook/callback', function (req, res, next) {

  console.log('on the way back');

  passport.authenticate('facebook', function (err, user, redirectURL) {
    console.log(' in the callback ');
    if (err) {
      return res.redirect('/#!/login');
    }

    if (!user) {
      return res.redirect('/#!/signup');
    }
    if (req.user) {
      console.log(req.user);
      res.cookie('user', JSON.stringify(req.user));
  }
    //actually storing the fact that they are logged in:
    req.login(user, function (err) {
      if (err) {
        return res.redirect('/#!/login');
      }

      return res.redirect('/');
    });
   })(req, res, next);
 });

app.get('/profile', function(req, res, next) {
  // get the data here from Mongo somehow?
});
```